# Filtering character on Haskell

Tags: haskell

I read the contents of a file but to work with them I need to filter 3 characters that I dont need.

I read an article where someone [read a .cgf file and filtered](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Read_a_configuration_file#Haskell) the "=", ";", "" and other characters that wasn't needed, so I tried somethig similar but I can't make it work:

```
--test filtering ::=
getLines = liftM lines . readFile

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "Enter a text file: "
    filename <- getLine
    --test filter ::=
    list <- filtering filename
    
    filtering :: String -> [String]
    filtering = folder clean . lines
        where clean = filter (not . flip any ["=", ":"] . (==) . take 1) 

    {-
    --this gets all the lines of the file and get it on a List, nut ::= is on the List too
    list <- getLines filename
    -}
```

Each line contects something like this: **"word ::= word word"** and the characers I want to filter are the "::=", so I can just have the words.

Is there any way I can do it in a line or do I have to read line by line in a do block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define a function that takes a file path as an argument, reads the associated file (`readFile`), breaks its contents up in lines (`lines`), then processes each line (`map`) by breaking it up in words (`words`) and only keeps the words that are not equal to "::=" (`(/= "::=")`), and returns (`return`) the resulting list of lists of remaining words. Straightforwardly:

```
filtering :: FilePath -> IO [[String]]
filtering fp = readFile fp >>= return . map go . lines
  where go line = [ w | w <- words line, w /= "::=" ]
```

To test it, let's create a text file `test.txt`:

```
one ::= two three
four ::= five six
```

Then:

```
> filtering "test.txt"
[["one","two","three"],["four","five","six"]]
```

---

Note that, here, we are using a list comprehension to express the filtering, but you can of course also use an explicit call to `filter`:

```
go = filter (/= "::=") . words
```

---

We're assuming here that processing a line by breaking it up in words is the right granularity for your problem. If you need finer granularity You can of course also traverse the line as a list of characters:

```
go line = words [ c | c <- line, c `notElem` "::=" ]
```

or

```
go = words . filter (`notElem` "::=")
```

This way, you filter character by character and only then break up the line in words.